# How To Call a Function from a Function in a diffrent file then return from the funtion you called to the function where you called it? python

Tags: python

My titles are pretty much my question (How To Call a Function from a Function in a different file then return from the function you called to the function where you called it?)

I've been trying to find an answer for this for a while here's my code:

module 1:

```
from module2 import store
def car():
     input = input("where would you like to drive 1: store 2: Park")
     store() ## for the sake of time ill just call this instead of writing an
```

module 2:

```
def store():
      input2 = input("What do you want to do go to 1: buy stuff 2: go back to the car")
      if input2 == "1":
          return
      else:
          ### buy stuff
```

Can I use a return statement with no parameters to quit the function entirely and not run the buy stuff code but then go back and continue running my car function, if the user wanted to go back to their car, or is there a better method?

Comment: Please edit your post to a) finish what you were saying at the end, and b) fix the formatting of the code snippets. To format the code, either use the `code sample` tool in the editing menu, or just indent each line of code by four spaces.

Comment: Also, when asking a question on Stack Overflow, always provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem at hand.

Comment: Yeah So I tried to make this yesterday day but it said I couldn't post it cause of 90 minutes between posts and so I can back today It all was saved except for the code I'm my second module

Comment: Sorry had a bit of a hard to correcting my post i hope you can understand it

Comment: Do you realize what the code `input = input("where would you like to drive 1: store 2: Park")` is trying to do? If it were to succeed the code would replace the input() built-in function with the value entered at the prompt. One example of why a Minimum Reproducible Example Code is desired.

Answer (score 4):

Response to the new part in OP's edited question:

Yes, you can always have a bare `return` statement for a function. The function in this case will return `None` when the condition is not met.

---

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking:

> How to import then call a function from another module.

Here's a simple example on how to do it:

```py
# file_1.py
def greet(name):
  return f'Hello, {name}!'
```

```py
# file_2.py
from file_1 import greet
print(greet('World'))
# 'Hello, World!'
```

For you specific example, you can use the information above and do something like this:

```py
# module1.py
from module2 import store
def car():
     input_1 = input("where would you like to drive 1: store 2: Park")
     input_2 = store()
     # then do whatever ....
```

```py
# module2.py
def store():
      ans = input(
    "What do you want to do go to 1: buy stuff 2: go back to the car")
      if ans == "2":
          return
      else:
          ### buy stuff
```